# How can I implement a search algorithm for a Tic Tac Toe AI in Python?

Tags: python, search, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe

We've covered BFS, DFS, iterative deepening, A*, hill climbing, minimax, and alpha-beta pruning in class so far. I'm not sure how I would code any of those searches into my Tic Tac Toe's AI. The computer has a 5-second time limit for this assignment.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random

# Tic-Tac-Toe Game Against A Computer

# Prints the board for the game to console output
def drawBoard():
    print("   | 1 | 2 | 3 ")
    print('---------------')
    print(' 1 | ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
    print('---------------')
    print(' 2 | ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
    print('---------------')
    print(' 3 | ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])

# Lets the player decide which symbol (X or O) he wants to be
def pickSymbol():
    symbol = ' '

    while not (symbol == 'X' or symbol == 'O'):
        print('Do you want to be symbol X, or the symbol O?')
        symbol = input().upper()

    # Return a list containing the player's symbol (first element) and the computer's symbol (second element)
    if symbol == 'X':
        return ['X', 'O']
    else:
        return ['O', 'X']

# Randomly determines if the player or the computer goes first
def pickFirst():
    if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
        return 'player'
    else:
        return 'computer'

# Checks that the x-coordinate the player chose is valid
def isValidX(x):
    try:
        intX = int(x)
        if not 1 <= intX <= 3:
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
        return False

    return True

# Checks that the y-coordinate the player chose is valid
def isValidY(y):
    try:
        intY = int(y)
        if not 1 <= intY <= 3:
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
        return False

    return True

# Converts a player's input coordinates to a move
def convertCoordinates(x, y):
    if x == 1:
        if y == 1:
            return 7
        elif y == 2:
            return 8
        else:
            return 9
    elif x == 2:
        if y == 1:
            return 4
        elif y == 2:
            return 5
        else:
            return 6
    else:
        if y == 1:
            return 1
        elif y == 2:
            return 2
        else:
            return 3

# Checks if a space for a given move is free
def isFree(move):
    return board[move] == ' '

# Gets the player's move
def getPlayerMove():
    while True:
        x = ' ' # arbitrary initial value before player input
        while not isValidX(x):
            print('Enter input x:')
            x = input()

        y = ' ' # arbitrary initial value before player input
        while not isValidY(y):
            print('Enter input y:')
            y = input()

        move = convertCoordinates(int(x),int(y))
        if not isFree(move):
            print('That space is taken. Please enter a different coordinate')
            continue
        else:
            break

    return move

# Gets the computer's move
def getComputerMove():
    return 9

# Places the move onto the board
def placeMove(move, sym):
    board[move] = sym

# Determines if the board is in a win state for a given symbol
def isWin(sym):
    return ((board[7] == sym and board[8] == sym and board[9] == sym) or # top
        (board[4] == sym and board[5] == sym and board[6] == sym) or     # middle     
        (board[1] == sym and board[2] == sym and board[3] == sym) or     # bottom
        (board[7] == sym and board[5] == sym and board[3] == sym) or     # diagonal
        (board[1] == sym and board[5] == sym and board[9] == sym) or     # diagonal
        (board[7] == sym and board[4] == sym and board[1] == sym) or     # left
        (board[8] == sym and board[5] == sym and board[2] == sym) or     # center
        (board[9] == sym and board[6] == sym and board[3] == sym))       # right

# Determines if the board is in a tie state
def isTie():
    return board.count('X') + board.count('O') == 9

# Prints the final output if the game is in a tie state
def tie():
    drawBoard()
    print('The game has ended in a tie.')

# Prints the final output if the game is in a win state for the PLAYER
def playerWin():
    drawBoard()
    print('Congratulations! You beat the computer!')

# Prints the final output if the game is in a win state for the COMPUTER
def computerWin():
    drawBoard()
    print('Sorry... the computer beat you.')

# The player makes a move
def playerTurn(playerSym):
    move = getPlayerMove()
    placeMove(move, playerSym)

# The computer makes a move
def computerTurn(computerSym):
    move = getComputerMove()
    placeMove(move, computerSym)

def main():
    print("Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe!")
    playerSym, computerSym = pickSymbol()
    turn = pickFirst()
    print("The " + turn + " will play first.")
    global board
    board = [' '] * 10

    while True:
        if turn == 'player':
            drawBoard()
            playerTurn(playerSym)
            if isWin(playerSym):
                playerWin()
                break
            if isTie():
                tie()
                break
            turn = 'computer'
        if turn == 'computer':
            drawBoard()
            computerTurn(computerSym)
            if isWin(computerSym):
                computerWin()
                break
            if isTie():
                tie()
                break
            turn = 'player'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Given the simplicity of tictactoe and its very small event space, and given the fact that there is always either one optimal move or various optimal moves being rotations of one another, the best way would be to hardcode the next move for each state of the board.

Comment: Use alpha/beta pruning, talk to your TA or just copy the code off wikipedia.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd answer this. It's like saying "We learned how to search graphs in class. How would I search a graph?" It's not clear what part you don't understand or whether you're just having difficulty translating concepts into practice, and it's difficult to give anything like an answer under so much ambiguity.

Comment: I'm not sure how to turn the tic tac toe board into a graph that I can search, if that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

Because I think this is as close to an actual answer as it can get, and taking a wild guess that this is the real source of the difficulty:

> I'm not sure how to turn the tic tac toe board into a graph that I can search, if that makes sense

The board is not the graph; the nodes of the graph are the possible board states resulting from taking turns playing moves. So you have a root node representing the current state, and then this is connected to the nodes resulting from each legal move for whoever's turn it is, and then nodes extending from there etc.

Comment: So I would have nodes representing the possible states of each board? Would the nodes go all the way down to a completed board?

Comment: That in general depends on the search algorithm and the game (you might also generate nodes on demand) - but tic-tac-toe is simple enough that you could feasibly build the whole graph up front starting from an empty board, yeah.